# What is the difference between Eclipse for Java and RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Do I have to download and install them separately? Or just the RCP package? Kinda confused.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse RCP includes Eclipse for Java plus all tools needed to create eclipse plugins and Rich Client or Rich Ajax Applications (RCP+RAP). With RCP you can use eclipse as a base platform for your applications.

Comment: You can download and install just the RCP one, it includes the functionality of the one for Java.